# Get text from UITextField on a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with prototype cells containing UITextFields. To configure these custome cells, I've created a UITableViewCell subclass. I've conected the textField to the cell subclass via an outlet `(nonatomic, weak)`.

On this subclass I've created a protocol for which the UITableViewController is its delegate so that everytime something changes in these textFields, the TableViewController knows about it. Basically I wanted this to save the values on the NSUserDefaults

Besides, in order to dynamically obtain values from these textFields, I can do something like this:

```
((TextFieldCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]]).textField.text
```

It works ok most of the times. However when the textField is outside of the view because it has scrolled, the vaulue I get from textField.text is (null). As soon as it gets in the view again, everything goes back to normal.

I tried to change the outlet from weak to strong but to no avail.

I guess I could define some private NSStrings on the class, and fill them out when the delegate protocol gets called. The thing is that I wanted to get my code as generic as possible, keeping the need for private variables as low as possible, mostly to simplify the cell generation code.

Is there any other way to get the values of the textFields when they are outside of the view?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thyraz said, the UITableView only keeps cells for the visible rect -- and a reasonable buffer to allow for scrolling.  Thats why 'reuse identifiers' are so very important, they indicate which cells can be used for which tables (critical when you have more than one table to worry about).  Unfortunately, that doesn't answer your question by itself.

The responsibility for storing the contents of those textViews isn't on the UITableView's shoulders.  It's *your* job to provide that data through the data source delegate protocols, and therefore you should be querying the data source for that information.

Edit:  Which means that yes, you should be storing this data somewhere else, usually in the form of properties on the view controller class that contains the table view.  I'd recommend the use of NSArray for the purpose, but you can also do it through dicts or even, at the *last* resort (and this is more a in theory you can do this, but it's an incredibly bad idea kind of thing), a series of properties.  Personally, I almost always use NSArrays because they're structured in a manner appropriate to the problem, but you could theoretically do it other ways.  (I've used a dict based structure exactly once, and that was a situation where my data was nested inside itself in a recursive structure)

Comment: No it doesn't answer the question directly, but helps me to understand why does it happen. So a kind of an answer anyway. Thanks a lot. I guess I was doing it correctly after all.

Comment: Yeah, it works with simple NSStrings, but NSArray is a good idea because it'll simplify the code on the cellForRow... Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Re:Comment 1:Understanding the 'why' is 9/10ths of any question *I* ask here; 'teach a man to fish' is a VERY important programming concept! Re:comment 2:Precisely.  UITableView is designed in a manner that is roughly analogous to an NSArray to begin with, which makes it natural and easily understood to use that data structure to provide the data.  (If you wanted to be strict, it's actually an array of arrays, but you frequently only have one section, making your 'top level' array a mono-element array, and I wouldn't waste time making an array data structure when I only have one element, ever)

Answer (score 1):

But you know that UITableView only keeps Cells for the visible rect?
When a cell leaves the screen, and a new cell is needed for another cell moving into the visible area, the old cell is reused for the new content.

So there is not one cell for each row of your table view.
And if your table contains a lot data, there are far more rows than cells.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of it. I just was surprised that the textField info was gone.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController doesn't keep cells around once off the screen. You can use the following pattern to get a previously used one as a memory management optimization, but you MUST assume that cells need to have the values reset on them every time they come onto the screen (even if dequeued) because there is no guarantee what the values will be.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
        cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell2.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }   
    switch( indexPath.section ) {
        case first_Section:
            if( row == 0 ) {
                cell1.textLabel.text = @"Some Text";
                cell1.accessoryView = [self myCustomViewControl];
                cell = cell1;
            }
            ... etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a code nitpick, but I tend to avoid switch statements in XCode/iOS; in my experience, they usually produce weird, difficult-to-debug errors when you least expect it.  On top of which, it looks like your code is designed to hard-code the entire table view, which I do _not_ like as a programming style.  It's easier to understand if you just hard code the data source, and makes the code more reuseable to boot.  (Edit:  Naturally, your preferences and results may vary)

Comment: Really?! I've been using switch statements in there since about 2008 and they work just fine. As for design style... this was simply an illustration of a concept as it sounded like the enquirer was not familiar with basic UITableViewController concepts. In general it is ALWAYS good practice to use a model/view pattern.

Comment: If you check my recent question history, there's a question on it because the fact that switch wasn't working was driving me nuts!  It seems like every time I try to use switches in iOS, I run into something that just doesn't work.  I can frequently 'break' the bug by using function calls instead of putting the work into the switch block itself, as well, but that leads to a profusion of function calls, which tends to clutter up the file just as badly as a series of if/else statements would.  (And I used to LOVE switches when I did C++ programming, so I don't think it's pure PEBKAC)

Comment: Send me a link, the only question I see of yours on your page having anything to do with tableview and switch is closed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this site includes a PM feature.  The question I mentioned was in fact closed, I managed to completely miss a nearly identical question which boiled down to 'switches just plain down't work with animations'.  Which kills the one example I remember, but there have been others and I don't think ALL of them involved animations.  (They occurred years ago, so my memory is fuzzy)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254585/how-can-a-switch-statement-cause-a-set-of-code-to-crash

Comment: k... well blow the lint off :) Don't want to confuse anyone. Anyway I DO KNOW switches work just fine in UITableViewController. May not always be the best design pattern, but that depends more on what is in your tableView and how generic each cell is.