# Adding Text Field Data to Table Cell

Tags: objective-c

How I can store text field data in a view controller into a `tableView` cell in a `TableViewController` With Xcode using data source?

That means when the user taps "+" it will show another view that has the text field. When the user enters the text and presses save, the entered data will be stored as a table cell.

Comment: try this link <http://stackoverflow.com/a/10737265/1223137>

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you understand data sources. Then you have to implement

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return self.data.count;
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {

 
        
        NSTableCellView * result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier" owner:self];

        result.textField = @"Your special string";
            
               
        return result;
    
}
```

After having setup it in IB like this *and* having connected the outlet of the Table View data source to your custom objects class (the class the above code is in) it should look like this[image]

Please notice I used the same identifier as in the code so that I can get the created table cell view back easily.

`self.data` could be an array for example in which you store all your underlying objects (for the cell creation).

Of course you could also add any kind of UI elements to the cell view as well. In this case I use a custom subclass for the cell view. You would have to do something like this then (and set your class as the class of the cell view within IB of course. This is the part in the screenshot that has an NSTableCellView currently in it. It had to be MyGreatCellView from now on):

```
@interface MyGreatCellView : NSTableCellView {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *files;
}

@property (assign) NSTextField *files;
```

Then you could also refer to `result.files` in the `tableView:vieForTableColumn:row` for example.

If something is unclear, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think this is for Mac (Cocoa) and I know that it is my fault I didn't mention that I need to know about iOS sorry because I am a new developer for iOS programs

Answer (score 1):

Getting the UITextField data onto a TableView Cell.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356758/get-text-from-uitextfield-on-a-tableviewcell) is a query for some one for the same issue.I think it will help you.